# Numpy: multiply arrays without losing precision / overflowing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using Numpy to do some basic operations on picture files. I'd like to perform the following operation:

```
in1, in2, out # some numpy arrays of dtype uint8
out = in1 * in2 / 256
```

However, due to the size of `uint8` and the rules of the modular arithmetic, an overflow occurs and the result is incorrect.

(The same problem doesn't occur in, for instance, in C++, where the intermediate result can be stored in a temporary space of a larger size.)

Another way would be to perform the multiplication twice: `out = in1/16 * in2/16`. However, this results in an innacurate value of the output.

One working solution would be manually setting every pixel:

```
out = numpy.empty(in1.shape, dtype="uint8")
for i in range(out.shape[0]):
    out[i] = int(in1[i])*in2[i]/256
```

This, however, requires you to know the exact number of dimensions in an array, and is generally inelegant (and possibly slower, because of the explicit loop(s)).

Another method would be to cast one of the source matrices into a type of a greater precision, e.g.:

```
out = in1.astype("uint16")*in2/256
```

This one, however, can be very memory-intensive, because it copies *the whole array*, instead of just keeping one variable with the intermediate result.

---

**Edit**

Here's a small example:

```
in1 = numpy.array([2, 4, 6], dtype="uint8")
in2 = numpy.array([128, 128, 128], dtype="uint8")

out = numpy.empty((3,), dtype="uint8")

# what I want to get: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=uint8)

out[:] = in1 * in2 / 256 # array([0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

---

So, here's my question: is there yet another way I'm missing? Is there a preferred (or just, efficient) way to do what I want to do, or do I just need to refactor my program?

Comment: I was hoping you could use `numpy.multiply(in1, in2, out)` with a 16-bit `out`, but apparently, that still truncates to 8 bits before storing the output to the 16-bit array.

Comment: If memory is so small that you can't afford several 16bit temporary arrays, then `numpy` is the wrong tool.

Comment: @MSeifert: We're not multiplying `in1` by `in2 / 256`; we're dividing `in1 * in2` by `256`. `in1 * in2` overflows. Also, the division is probably intended to be floordiv, not truediv.

Comment: If creating and discarding giant scratch arrays everywhere isn't feasible for you, NumPy isn't going to serve your needs. NumPy loves its giant scratch arrays. You'll end up writing everything in C-like Numba or Cython to avoid the scratch arrays, or taking a 100x speed hit to write everything in plain Python loops.

Comment: Ok, so it isn't doable then.

Thank you for input anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In numpy you can use the [`dtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#overriding-ufunc-behavior) argument to calulcate the temporary array in another dtype without explicitly copying the array:

```
>>> out = np.multiply(in1, in2, dtype=np.uint16)  # overflow safe multiplication
>>> np.floor_divide(out, 256, out=out)            # in-place division
>>> out
array([1, 2, 3], dtype=uint16)
```

However then `out` will be an `uint16` array (because one can't chain ufuncs with numpy). But it avoids temporary arrays as much as possible.

Comment: Huh. Ufuncs accept a dtype argument? That's not in the `numpy.multiply` docs.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of useful (and almost unknown) arguments, e.g. `where`. These hide in the general "ufunc" documentation I linked in the answer :)

Comment: I'm not sure this actually avoids creating 16-bit temporary arrays for the inputs.

Comment: @user2357112 At least superficial testing with `a = np.ones((100_000_000), dtype=np.float16); np.multiply(a, a, dtype=np.float64)` doesn't show a temporary rise in memory usage that would indicate that there is more than one `float64` array. Be careful to adjust the number depending on your RAM because that creates an almost 1GB array.